# How to show or hide small view containing web page in iOS app based on certain conditions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, cordova

We're building an iPhone app and using this iAd plugin from PhoneGap: https://github.com/shazron/iAdPlugin/blob/master/SAiOSAdPlugin.m.

Because we built the app with HTML5, not Objective-C, and don't know how to adjust the plug-in.

When iAd lacks inventory, it displays a blank, white rectangle (320x50). We would like to display a 320x50 web page instead of the white rectangle, acting as a fallback ad, only show iAd when it has ad inventory again.

We know it's necessary to include code in `(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError*)error`, but would love tips on what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    banner.hidden = YES;
    UIWebView *webview = ... //Make it.
    webview.frame = banner.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
}
```

Unless I'm missing something huge, this should work - remember to set the `banner`s `delegate` to `self`, though.

Comment: thanks! quick question: isn't this inefficient since we're creating the banner every time there is an error (i.e., there is no ad for iAd to render)? thanks again.

Comment: also what do you mean by "remember to set the banners delegate to self"

Comment: @Crashalot **1.** It's just a bare-bones example. In the real world, you would probably keep a reference to the web view, and init it at startup, then add and remove it from the hierarchy as needed.

Comment: @Crashalot **2.** To receive the `didFailToReceiveAd` method, you need to be the banner view's delegate - set either in Interface Builder (just like a table view), or in code.

Comment: cool, thanks! so if we're modifying SAiOSAdPlugin.m (we will submit it  a pull request to benefit the community), then we need to add code to the __prepare method that creates the web view? and then modify didFailToReceiveAdWithError to hide iAd while showing the webview? does setting webview.hidden = NO automatically show the web view? thanks again!

Comment: @Crash I don't know anything about the plugin in question, but that sounds about right. As always, try it! If it doesn't work, ask another question here (after Googling :).

Comment: ok, thanks! here's the plugin in case you're curious: https://github.com/shazron/iAdPlugin/blob/master/SAiOSAdPlugin.m. also, is setting webview.hidden = NO all that's necessary to show the webview? thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot Yes, **as long as it is in the subview tree**. Add it as a subview, then set hidden to YES/NO as you like. You could also use the `alpha`, which gives you finer grain control, and is animatable.

Comment: it's a little confusing as the github.com/shazron/iAdPlugin/blob/master/SAiOSAdPlugin.m code uses self.bannerIsVisible to show/hide the view. thanks anyway. we'll try to figure it out.

Comment: we tried using your code, but the UIWebView won't appear. we posted the question here if you could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867493/trouble-hiding-iad-banner-and-displaying-uiwebview-in-its-place. thanks again.

Comment: hey @undo, you there still? two more quick questions if you have time?

Comment: @Crashalot I'm going to be gone for a few hours - would tomorrow work? If they're quick, I can try to answer them fast right now, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31052/discussion-between-crashalot-and-undo)